# Comparing times in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdateformatter

I am creating an iOS app using swift language. From backend service api, i receives a parameter called time and it's value in string format(eg:- 06:15 PM, 10:00 AM).I need to compare this string with current time. How it is possible using dateformatter?

Comment: That is a bad API. “06:15 PM” is a localized string, just a time without day/month/year, and without timezone. Better send a (UNIX) timestamp or an ISO formatted date string.

Comment: What does `"06:15 PM, 10:00 AM"` mean? Btw SO it is not a code writing service. Edit your question and show what you have tried and the issues you are facing

Comment: Well how would you know what date the time refers to? For example is it 6pm today or yesterday or tomorrow or five years ago?. If possible, have the response changed to epoch time. Things then will be more specific and manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible until and unless you have the date component as well. If you or people you know do not control the response then the only possible way out would be to make your own logic.

Step 1: Would be to get the current date and time.

Step 2: Format it to reflect the time format you seek such as AM/PM.

Step 3: Make your own custom function where you calculate the difference between two times.

P.S - You would require Dateformatter for step two only